# rexx reading file data onto panel

Tags: panel, rexx

can you please suggest me the manual or example codes on how i can read the content of a file to be displayed in a rexx panel.
the number of lines from the file can vary and so cannot use the static manner.

thanks,
Samuel Mathews.

Comment: should we assume you are working on z/OS?

Answer (score 3):

In ZOS to read the file in rexx use the [execio](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.ikjc300/ikj4c310103.htm) command
i.e.

```
"EXECIO  *  DISKR  myindd  (STEM fileContentsVar."
```

Reads the file into a stem variable (fileContentsVar.0 holds the number of records and
fileContentsVar.1 ... hold the actual data).

You could store the file contents in a [ISPF table](http://rexxpertise.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/ispf-tables-defining-and-building.html) and display the table using the
[TBDispl](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.f54sg00/ispzsg80360.htm) command

The rexx code will be roughly

```
address ispexec
'tbcreate myfile names(line)'

do i=1 to fileContentsVar.0
   line = fileContentsVar.i
   'tbadd myfile'
end
'tbtop myfile'
'tbdispl mypanel'
'tbend myfile'
```

For an example of a table-panel definition see http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.f54dg00%2Fispzdg8040.htm

A table-panel would look like:

```
************************************************************
* )Attr                                                    *
*   @ Type(output) Intens(low) Just(asis)   Caps(off)      *
* )Body                                                    *
* -------------------- ????????????????? ----------------- *
* +Command ==>Cmdfld                    +Scroll ==>_samt+  *   
* +                                                        *    
* This table shows  ...                                    *    
*                                                          *   
* Line                                                     * 
* )Model                                                   *   ---- The model setion holds the
* @line                           +                        *        Table display section
*                                                          *
* )Init                                                    *
*   &samt=page                                             *
* )Proc                                                    *
* )End                                                     *
************************************************************
```

Comment: thanks, i wil chk and let you know the updates... yes, am workin in ZOS